# How can i set elements id in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
function addToDoList() {
    toDoForm.addEventListener('submit', event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        toDoArray.push(toDoInput.value);
        const li = document.createElement("li"); 
        const delButton = document.createElement("button");
        delButton.innerHTML = "X";
        const span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerHTML = toDoInput.value;
        li.appendChild(span);
        li.appendChild(delButton);
        toDoList.appendChild(li);
        toDoInput.value = "";
    });
}
```

Here's my code, when i input a value, it displays on list. And i want to give an id to each of list. How can i do that?

Comment: You can use `setAttribute` method on the list item to set an id

Comment: [javascript set element id](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+set+element+id&t=vivaldi&ia=web)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can get all your elements in the list with `document.querySelectorAll('li')`
- Then iterate over your elements and give every element a specific id. To give every element a unique id use the indice which will increment in every iteration. Then assign this id to the id property of the element

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((val, ind) => {
  val.id = "elem" + (ind + 1);
})

document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((val, ind) => {
  console.log(val.id);
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Simpler to use element.id property as setter

Answer (score 0):

You should use setAttribute to set an id for dom element

```
li.setAttribute("id" , "your custom id");
```

Comment: "to each of list" the OP said